# Find several strings in a .txt file, and assign them to a different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a SQL file, that I have converted to a txt file.

The final idea is to do a readline() with Python3 and find a specific string, and return only the lines that have this string.

For example, imagine this file.txt:

```
*hello, how are you
I am fine, --- thanks*/
What a wonderful day
Yes, it ---is
Regards---*
```

I need to print (or assign a variable/variables) only the lines where the string "---" appears:

```
*I am fine, --- thanks*/
Yes, it ---is
Regards---*
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have a SQL file, that I have converted to a txt file."- that already sounds suspect, but ignoring that, you want to test if a substring is in a line? `for line in lines: if '---' in line:`

Comment: The idea is to print (or assign a variables) only the lines where appears '---'

Comment: You need to include your code, and a *specific* input and desired output, I can't guess exactly what you want from these comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
print ([line for line in open("test.txt").readlines() if "---" in line])
```

If you want the output in separate lines without "\n" and not list:

```
my_list = [line.strip() for line in open("test.txt").readlines() if "---" in line]
for line in my_list:
    print(line)
```

line.strip() will remove "\n".

Comment: Thanks. It works correctly. 
When I print all the lines are separated by 
'linexxxxx \n, 'linexxxxx \n'

Comment: Exactly. Thank you..
With "line.strip()" :
"Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace"